Why would `eval('dict('+s+')')` work but not `literal_eval('dict('+s+')')`?
I could do this with eval():
>>> s = 'hello=True,world="foobar"'
>>> eval('dict('+s+')')
{'hello': True, 'world': 'foobar'}

but with literal_eval():
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('dict('+s+')')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 110, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 109, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 83, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 74, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 71, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(msg + f': {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Call object at 0x1014cb940>

Q (part 1): Why would eval() work but not literal_eval()?
Q (part 2): Is there a name for the '+s+' style/format?
Q (part 3): Is it possible to use something like the +s+ with literal_eval()?

dict() is a function call; eval_literal isn't permitted to perform function calls. {} is the form of a literal dict.

Re: part 2... the name I would use is "string concatenation". To be very clear, the problem has nothing whatsoever to do with string concatenation; you'd have the exact same error with eval_literal('dict(hello=True,world="foobar")') with no +s+ involved anywhere at all.

Re: part 3, yes, if you're using it in a context where you aren't requesting that a function call take place.

In that case the dict('+s+') is some special initialization of dict object from string, is my understanding right? Or is it something that eval is doing when reading the +s+?

No, it's not special syntax.

You're literally just concatenating the string dict(, the string hello=True,world="foobar" and the string ) together into one longer string and passing that string to eval; eval is what makes the string be executed as code.

Ah got it, thanks for the explanation! You should put the above comments in the answer =)

So eval doesn't know that +s+ was used at all -- the + operators were used to concatenate the smaller strings together into one bigger string before eval is ever started.

It was tricky but it's 'dict( + s + )', I get it now.

Might be worth mentioning f"dict({s}"

This isn't special syntax: +s+ doesn't have any atypical meaning. You're just concatenating strings together, the same way 'abc' + 'def' evaluates to 'abcdef'.
In this case, when you concatenate the string 'dict(', the string 'hello=True,world="foobar"', and the string ')' together, you get 'dict(hello=True,world="foobar")'.
dict(hello=True,world="foobar") is valid Python code (so eval can run it), but it's not a valid literal definition (because dict is a function call, not literal syntax), so ast.literal_eval() correctly refuses it.
